# Missing Operator in WinPE

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, winpe

I have one Batch file which I need to run in WinPE but I am getting "Missing Operator" error. I am able to run the Batch file in Normal Windows 7.

I think in WinPE certain Env. Variable are not working.

Can someone please help?

#### Code:

```
rem Print the percentage encrypted details 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%%i %%j"=="Percentage Encrypted:" (
set var=%%k 
set var=!var:~0,-1! 
if !Percent! LSS !var! (
echo Percentage Encrypted is !Percent! 
set /A Percent=!var!/5 
set /A Percent=!Percent!*5+5
)
if !Percent!==!var!(
echo Percentage Encrypted is !Percent!set /A Percent=!Percent!+5
)
)
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of your batch file?

Comment: if you are using the `if` command: don't forget to surround the operator's in `"` as to prevent any null variables causing an error. Try doing: `if "%var1%"="%var2%" REM Avoiding Null Errors.`

Comment: rem Print the percentage encrypted details
 if "%%i %%j"=="Percentage Encrypted:" (
  set var=%%k
  set var=!var:~0,-1!
  
  if !Percent! LSS !var! (
   echo Percentage Encrypted is !Percent!
   set /A Percent=!var!/5
   set /A Percent=!Percent!*5+5
  )
  
  if !Percent!==!var! (
   echo Percentage Encrypted is !Percent!
   set /A Percent=!Percent!+5
  )

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in my comment, the problem is due to a null variable. To prevent the code from raising errors you would need to surround it in double quotes however it would not function the way you would want it to without the variable values.

I noticed your code is structured as if it is a part of a `for-loop`. If so, please show us the full code to try assisting you:

```
rem Print the percentage encrypted details 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if "%%i %%j"=="Percentage Encrypted:" (
set var=%%k 
set var=!var:~0,-1! 
if "!Percent!" LSS "!var!" (
echo Percentage Encrypted is !Percent! 
set /A Percent=!var!/5 
set /A Percent=!Percent!*5+5
)
if "!Percent!"=="!var!"(
echo Percentage Encrypted is !Percent!set /A Percent=!Percent!+5
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the problem is that the statement is too close to the open parenthesis `(` and you also might want to drop the `set /a` on a separate line ;), see proposed change below:

```
if "!Percent!"=="!var!" (
echo Percentage Encrypted is !Percent!
set /A Percent=!Percent!+5
)
```